# install a template with content

Tags: joomla, themes, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

I am new to Joomla, trying to install this template http://demo.web-komp.eu/jomi/#page, following the instructions from here http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Installing_a_template.

But i am not getting any features of theme like menus, sliders, images. This is the out put on activating the theme : [image]

How can I import theme with content in Joomla 3.2?

Comment: Well, did you do this part of the tutorial: `Install Content From A Template [Advanced Topic]` ?

Comment: i tried but i cant see 'Import Content from Template' button in admin page.

Comment: Well, I am not the Joomla expert, but I'd say that is why you do not have the content.

Comment: You need to assign you chosen modules to position that belong to the template. Different templates use different position names ;)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1) Install the template: Extensions->Extension Manager->Upload zip file and install.

2) Choose your new template as the default template of the site: Extensions->Template Manager->Click on the star next to the new template installed.

3) Assign the modules to your new template: You must go to the Module Manger and changes the positions of all of the modules to the new positions of the template you installed.

If you would like to know what positions your template has do the following:

Go to Template Manager and on the right top corner click on options. You will see this: Preview Module Positions. Click enabled and save and close.

Now to view the positions your template has just type in the url this: ?tp=1

Example: www.test.com/demo?tp=1

Hope this helps you out :).

Comment: Don't forget to disable it once you have finished using it ;)